# Decide which webpack.resolve.modules will be used by a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-plugin

```
{
  resolve: {
    extensions: [...],
      modules: [...],
      alias: {
      ...
    },
    plugins: [...],
  }
}
```

I have a multiple folders and in each fo them, i use non-relative path inside the `require`.

When I `require` from file in folder `A` to other file in folder `B`, I want to use a different `modules` array  to resolve modules because some of the files in both of the folders has the same name.

How can I do that?

---

What I have tried so far:

- I failed to create a resolve-plugin due to lack of proper documentation/ examples that uses the latest webpack version. Also, I will probably re-implement alot that is already implemented because I will need to resolve everything by my self - which is a bad idea.